# Algorithm stuck in a loop

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14

I have an exercise where I'm given a limit number ( m ), and I need to show all prime numbers, which also have their permutations prime. I've developed this algorithm which is stuck after '11', so I think the problem is at even numbers. To translate the functions:

1. The first function reads the number limit - m;
2. The second function checks if a number is prime or not;
3. The third function returns the number formed by commuting a given number's digits to the left ( 1234 - 2341 )
4. The fourth function develops the algorithm.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

///In: -
///Out: m - limita
void citireDate(int &m)
{
    cout << "Limita m: "; cin >> m;
}

///In: un numar
///Out: k, care poate lua valori de 0 sau 1: 0 = prim
///                                          1 = neprim
int prim(int nr)
{
    int d = 2, k = 0;
    while(d*d<=nr&&k==0)
    {
        if(nr%d==0)
            k=1;
        d++;
    }
    return k;
}

///In: un numar
///Out: numarul format prin permutarea cifrelor numarului primit spre stanga
int permutareStanga(int nr)
{
    int nrCif = log10(nr);
    int putere = pow(10.0, nrCif);
    int primaCif = nr / putere,
        restCif  = nr % putere;
    return restCif*10 + primaCif;
}

///In: m
///Out: numerele prime permutabile, mai mici decat m;
void algoritmPermutabile(int m)
{
    for(int i = 11; i<m; i++)
    {
        int primalitate = prim(i);
        if(primalitate==0)
        {
            int p = permutareStanga(i);
            int k1 = 0;
            while(k1==0&&p!=i)
            {
                int d1 = 2, k2=0;
                while(d1*d1<=p&&k2==0)
                {
                    if(p%d1==0)
                        k2=1;
                }
                if(k2==1)
                    k1=1;
                permutareStanga(p);
            }
            if(k1==0)
                cout << i << " ";
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int m;
    citireDate(m);
    algoritmPermutabile(m);
    cout<<"\nProgram terminat";
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for reading!

**Conclusion:**
I forgot to add 1 to d1, so it was stuck in a endless loop with d1 = 2...

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: @NathanOliver you were so right about the debugger - it really is a essential tool.

Comment: Rather than edit your question to include the answer, you can answer your question yourself (and mark that answer as accepted).

Comment: `while(d1*d1<=p&&k2==0) { if(p%d1==0) k2=1; }` seems the culprit, when if-condition is false

Comment: The `while(k1==0&&p!=i)` loop repeats with the same `p` over and and over and over...

Comment: It only takes a few minutes to add some tracing outputs and see where you get stuck. This is often much more convenient than messing with a debugger.